# TListItem.Checked switches itself to True after Assign()

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-7, listviewitem

I came across some unexpected behaviour of TListItem. Check the following test code:

```
  var
  Item: TListItem;

  //...

  ListView1.Checkboxes := True;
  with ListView1.Items.Add do
  begin
    Caption := 'old item';
    Checked := False;
  end;

  Item := TListItem.Create(ListView1.Items);
  Item.Caption := 'new item';
  Item.Checked := False;

  ListView1.Items[0].Assign(Item);

  Assert(ListView1.Items[0].Caption = 'new item');
  Assert(ListView1.Items[0].Checked = False); //WTF
```

Assertion failure occurs, as Checked property somehow switches itself to True. I didn't find any remarks on this behaviour in the help file.

Is this a bug or a feature?

I'm using Delphi 7 with all updates.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Assign()`. Insert `Assert(not Item.Checked);` before the 'Assign' and you'll see it fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi comes with VCL source code. Look in `ComCtrls.pas` for the implementation of `TListItem` and `TListView`.

Had you enabled "Use debug DCUs" in your project options and then stepped through the `TListItem` source code with the debugger, you would have seen *exactly* what is happening.  `Item.Checked := False` fails, and reading `Item.Checked` always returns `True`, because `Item.Index` is -1 (since you bypassed `TListItems.Add()`).

The `TListItem.GetChecked()` getter method does not handle the possibility that the `ListView_GetCheckState()` macro (which is a wrapper for the `LVM_GETITEMSTATE` message) is failing due to being passed an invalid item index.

Manually creating a `TListItem` object is not enough to add the item to the underlying Win32 ListView control.  If you create a `TListItem` via means other than `TListItems.Add()` or `TLisItem.Insert()`, you must call `TListItems.AddItem()` to insert the `TListitem` into the underlying ListView control.